# React.js: Inline styling of particular elements of an SVG?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I'm in the process of learning React right now, and I'm importing an SVG usig "svg-react-loader". I was wondering if there is a way to style parts of the SVG using inline styling? For example if my `svg` has `rect` and `circle` elements in it, it is possible to style those two shapes differently? My intuition was to have something like this:

```
var style = {
    '.rect': {
        stroke:"green"
    },
    '.circle': {
        stroke:"red"
    }
}

render() {
    return (<TestSVG style={style}/>)
};
```

Of course, this doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should update your profile name at-least.